# Docker swarm container monitoring

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have been on a typical journey of:

1. deploying software on a machine
2. deploying software in a container
3. deploying software using docker swarm

The need for this journey is that swarm removes a large portion of micro-managing resources and machine allocation etc.

There is, however, a hurdle I am trying to overcome.

For point one and two, we have heavy monitoring of our software using a tool (Zabbix) which has given us great insights into any problems or metrics.

As we migrate to point three, how does one monitor an individual container?

**To give a real-world illustration:**

I have software that is "buggy", every now and then it dies. The health check would typically fail and a new container would start with no service interruption. My question is,

- How am I aware that this has occurred in order to investigate a potential problem ?
- One potential solution is to monitor the docker swarm event stream; is this the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is not to handle this information)) You will get tired of such useless information like containers restarts.

Anyway, there is couple of tools to monitor docker with prometheus:

- Google [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor)
- [Docker experimental prometheus metrics](https://docs.docker.com/config/thirdparty/prometheus/)

But it requires installation of prometheus, alert-manager, find metrics for triggering and set up alert rules.

Or maybe try to find zabbix tool for monitoring docker containers.